# ORA-04030: out of process memory error during an export

Tags: oracle

I am having the following error while exporting a 1.5GB table from an Oracle 10g database to a CSV file using sqlplus spool:

> ORA-04030: out of process memory when trying to allocate 112 bytes (kxs-heap-w,kghalp : evarxalc)

I am having the following error while exporting a 1.5GB table from an Oracle 10g database to a CSV file using sqlplus spool.

The request is as follows:

```
select column1
 ||'|'||column2
 ||'|'||column3
 ||'|'||column4
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 ||'|'||column93
 from table;
```

Any idea why I am getting this error?
 The export used to work on the same table.

Comment: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1363891100346045112 -- perhaps your table got bigger, your access to memory got smaller, or... ?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith : So basically, because the table is too big, I need more memory in order to export it?

Comment: That would be my guess as well @tabby. You could try breaking this up into batches, say 500MB of data at a time, just be sure to use the SPOOL file.csv APPEND command.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith : You mean I can try to spool like the 1st 500k rows and then using'' SPOOL file.csv append'' to append the different files?  Or is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: append will write the 2nd or 3rd set of records to the same file you used for the first

Comment: But then I will need to have different scripts to do the spool?

Comment: a script can have more than 1 query in it